# How keep tooltip when is clicked on EditorFor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@title = "We ask for your age only for statistical purposes."} })
```

Tooltip appears when hover over it. How to make when it is clicked to appear tooltip message like a hint and keep state until changes other EditorFor ?

Something like this http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/image.axd?picture=image_145.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a javascript library to get this custom behavior.

JQuery UI has an implementation http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

### EDIT

You are looking for something that when clicked shows some UI. This would be more like a Popup or Popover. Bootstrap has a nice implementation:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: but tooltip mesage appears when is hover with mouse , but i need to be onclick